# Función en Javascript solo funciona con un parámetro

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando una aplicación web para buscar libros y guardarlos en una base de datos. Para ello, al hacer la búsqueda el html que muestra los resultados se genera a través de document.getElementById("#").innerHTML
. Para una visualizarlo mejor, este sería el resultado al realizar la búsqueda: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hebuU.jpg

La llamada a la función está dentro de este HTML generado desde Javascript pasándole un parámetro en concreto, y la cosa es que haciendo click en el botón del primer resultado, el libro se guarda correctamente en la base de datos a través de php. Sin embargo, al hacer click en cualquiera de los botones siguientes, no hace nada y he comprobado a través de Sources en la Consola que haciendo click en ellos a la función no le entra ningún parámetro. Me gustaría saber qué está provocando este comportamiento.

Mi Javascript (la función en concreto está al final del todo):

```
var htmlcontent = "";
var thumb = "";
var author = "";
var isbnL = "";
var title = "";
var arr = new Array();
var resultados = new Array();

$("#search_form").submit(function (e) {
  $("#books").html("");

  e.preventDefault();

  function Libro(isbn, titulo, autor, imagen) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.autor = autor;
    this.imagen = imagen;

    //GETTER
    this.getIsbn = function () {
      return this.isbn;
    }

    this.getTitulo = function () {
      return this.titulo;
    }

    this.getAutor = function () {
      return this.autor;
    }
    this.getImagen = function () {
      return this.imagen;
    }
  }
  var searchQuery = $("#search_txt").val();
  searchQuery = searchQuery.split(" ").join("+");

  var buscar = $("#search_txt").val();
  if (buscar == "") {
    alert("Por favor, introduce algún término de búsqueda");
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + searchQuery,
    success: function (json) {

      arr = json.items;
      arr.forEach(function (dato) {
        if (typeof dato.volumeInfo.imageLinks != "undefined") {
          thumb = dato.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail;
        } else {
          thumb = "http://i.imgur.com/oM3MdAi.png";
        }
        // AUTHOR
        if (typeof dato.volumeInfo.authors != "undefined") {
          author = dato.volumeInfo.authors[0];
        }

        if (typeof dato.volumeInfo.title != "undefined") {
          title = dato.volumeInfo.title[0];
        }

        if (typeof dato.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers != "undefined") {
          isbnL = dato.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier;
        }

        var miLibro = new Libro(isbnL, dato.volumeInfo.title, author);
        resultados.push(miLibro);

        htmlcontent +=
          "<div class='cards'><div class='card-content'><div class='media'><div class='media-left'><figure class='image is-128x128'><img src='" + thumb + "' alt='alt text' /></figure></div><div class='media-content'><p class='title is-4'>" +
          dato.volumeInfo.title + "</p><p class='subtitle is-6'>" + author + "</p><button id='add' class='button is-primary add' onclick='guardarLibro(" + isbnL + ") '>Añadir a mi lista</button></div></div></div></div>";

        document.getElementById("books").innerHTML =
          "<div>" + htmlcontent + "</div><br>";
      }),
        document.getElementById("books").innerHTML =
        "<div>" + htmlcontent + "</div><br>";
      console.log(resultados);

    }
  });
});

function guardarLibro(isbn) {
  $(document).on("click", ".add", function () {

    console.log("boton pulsado");
    console.log(isbn);

    $("#add").replaceWith("<i class='fas fa-check-circle' style='color=#02c39a;'></i>Añadido");

    for (var i = 0; i < resultados.length; i++) {
      if (resultados[i].isbn == isbn) {
        isbnL = resultados[i].getIsbn();
        title = resultados[i].getTitulo();
        author = resultados[i].getAutor();
        thumb = resultados[i].getImagen();
      }
    }
    console.log(title);

    var url = 'guardarlibro.php';
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        isbnL, title, author, thumb

      },
      success: function (response) {
        console.log("JS ok");

      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la función `guardarLibro` se ejecuta cuando se hace clic en el botón y dentro agregas nuevamente el evento *click* `$(document).on("click", ".add", function () { ... })` creando nuevas funciones con cada clic y donde no recibes el parámetro.

Simplemente ejecuta el código necesario para buscar el atributo y ejecutar la petición AJAX:

```
function guardarLibro(isbn) {
    console.log("boton pulsado");
    console.log(isbn);

    $("#add").replaceWith("<i class='fas fa-check-circle' style='color=#02c39a;'></i>Añadido");

    for (var i = 0; i < resultados.length; i++) {
      if (resultados[i].isbn == isbn) {
        isbnL = resultados[i].getIsbn();
        title = resultados[i].getTitulo();
        author = resultados[i].getAutor();
        thumb = resultados[i].getImagen();
      }
    }
    console.log(title);

    var url = 'guardarlibro.php';
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        isbnL, title, author, thumb

      },
      success: function (response) {
        console.log("JS ok");

      }
    });
}
```

Adicionalmente, al generar el HTML, te recomiendo usar [plantillas de cadenas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) para evitar concatenar, quedando tu código más legible y encerrando entre comillas el parámetro que envías a la función, porque es una cadena:

```
htmlcontent += `
  <div class="cards"><div class="card-content"><div class="media">
    <div class="media-left">
      <figure class="image is-128x128"><img src="${thumb}" alt="alt text" /></figure>
    </div>
    <div class="media-content">
      <p class="title is-4">${dato.volumeInfo.title}</p>
      <p class="subtitle is-6">${author}</p>
      <button id="add" class="button is-primary add" onclick="guardarLibro('${isbnL}');">Añadir a mi lista</button>
    </div>
  </div></div></div>`;
```

**Importante:** Revisando la consola del navegador, seguramente podrás encontrar este tipo de errores fácilmente.

Comment: ¡Gracias! La verdad es que está bien deshacerse de código innecesario, aunque el problema persiste. Con el primer item todo se ejecuta correctamente pero sigue sin llegar nada a la función con el resto de opciones :(

Comment: @SaraB, actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Ahora sí que sí, ¡muchísimas gracias! No conocía las plantillas de cadena y ahora creo que lo voy a usar un montón ya que es más que útil.